# Chrome extension contextMenu is undefined from background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to run a Chrome extension that has a right click functionality. This is the permissions section in `manifest.json`:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
```

My background script - `background.ts`:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({ title: "click me", onclick: myClickAction });

function myClickAction() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

This is what I see in the background page console:
[image]

Looking for guidance and suggestions on how to fix!

Comment: Add quotes around `title` and `onclick` like this: `chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": "click me", "onclick": myClickAction });`

Comment: Hmm still the same results - I feel like the root problem here is that the global `chrome` variable doesn't have `contextMenus` instantiated for some reason..

Comment: Quotes aren't necessary in JS literals. You probably forgot to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json. Another reason might be some custom library you're using that modifies `chrome`.

Comment: Yes! I had to rebuild and reload the extension and things worked!

Comment: In case anyone else had issues with this, I was turning my extension on and off which restarted the background.js page, but i had to reload/unpack or w/e to get the manifest.json to register